# How do I check if a directory has child directories?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

Using bash, how do I write an if statement that checks if a certain directory, stored in the a script variable named "$DIR", contains child directories that are not "." or ".."?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Check into using http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, things have changed in the last 9 years! The dot dirs are no longer returned as part of find and instead the directory specified in the `find` command is.

So, if you want to stay with this approach:

```
#!/bin/bash
subdircount=$(find /tmp/test -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)

if [[ "$subdircount" -eq 1 ]]
then
    echo "none of interest"
else
    echo "something is in there"
fi
```

(originally accepted answer from 2011)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
subdircount=`find /d/temp/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l`

if [ $subdircount -eq 2 ]
then
    echo "none of interest"
else
    echo "something is in there"
fi
```

Comment: @AI G when i tried the above `find` command it was returning the folder path `/d/temp` if no sub folders were present. `./` and `../` were not counted.

Comment: @Antarus I get the same. This solution, as given, doesn't work for me. I get a result of 1 for an empty directory, and one more for each directory that is present (e.g. a result of 3 if there are 2 subdirectories). I am using git bash though, so it's not 'proper' bash I guess...

Answer (score 14):

Here's a more minimalist solution that will perform the test in a single line..

```
ls $DIR/*/ >/dev/null 2>&1 ; 

if [ $? == 0 ]; 
then 
  echo Subdirs
else 
  echo No-subdirs
fi
```

By putting `/` after the `*` wildcard you select only directories, so if there is no directories then `ls` returns error-status **2** and prints the message `ls: cannot access <dir>/*/: No such file or directory`. The `2>&1` captures **stderr** and pipes it into **stdout** and then the whole lot gets piped to **null** (which gets rid of the regular ls output too, when there is files).

Comment: More minimalist: `ls $DIR/*/ &>/dev/null && echo Subdirs || echo No-subdirs`

Comment: @ingydotnet except for that the if/else bit isn’t actually part of the solution. It’s just demonstrating the ‘$?’ variable. Nice shorthand though!

Comment: @ingydotnet However, is that solution portable to other shells, like ksh?

Comment: The absolute minimalist and cross shell compatible would be to put the following in a function `ls $1/*/ >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure what you trying to do here, but you can use `find`:

```
find /path/to/root/directory -type d
```

If you want to script it:

```
find $DIR/* -type d
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This finds the root directory, too, not just the children

Comment: Try `find /path/to/root/directory -mindepth 1 -type d`

Answer (score 2):

Try this as the condition you test against:

```
subdirs=$(ls  -d $DIR/.*/ | grep -v "/./\|/../")
```

subdirs will be empty if there are no subdirectories

Comment: Hi, I like this solution because it puts the contents into an array that I can use later.  But the $DIR variable contains a space in the directory names and this seems to be messing up the expression.

Answer (score 2):

A solution in pure bash, without needing any other program execution.  This is not the most compact solution, but if run in a loop, it could be more efficient because no process creation is needed.  If there is a lot of files in `'$dir'`, the filename expansion could break though.

```
shopt -s dotglob   # To include directories beginning by '.' in file expansion.
nbdir=0
for f in $dir/*
do
  if [ -d $f ]
  then
    nbdir=$((nbdir+1))
  fi
done

if [ nbdir -gt 0 ]
then
   echo "Subdirs"
else
   echo "No-Subdirs"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case it doesn't work as @AIG wrote - for empty dir I got subdircount=1 (find returns only dir itself).

what works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
subdircount=`find /d/temp/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l`
if [ $subdircount -ge 2 ]
then
    echo "not empty"
else
    echo "empty"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to know if a directory has any subdirectories. For this purpose I don't need recursion, and I don't care what they are. So:

```
(find -L . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
num_child=`ls -al $DIR | grep -c -v ^d`
```

If $num_child > 2, then you have child directories. If you do not want hidden directories, replace ls -al with ls -l.

```
if [ $num_child -gt 2 ]
then
    echo "$num_child child directories!"
fi
```

Comment: is the output of ls standardized across flavors of unixoid systems?

Comment: As far as I've seen (linux / opensolaris / freebsd), yes.

Comment: Yes, it is standard.  See the the specification [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html).  A previous version says the same [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/ls.html).  A would guess that the fist version of the standard (POSIX) says the same, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the best answer you will ever see on this issue.

```
function hasDirs ()
{
    declare $targetDir="$1"    # Where targetDir ends in a forward slash /
    ls -ld ${targetDir}*/
}
```

If you are already in the target directory:

```
if hasDirs ./
then

fi
```

If you want to know about another directory:

```
if hasDirs /var/local/   # Notice the ending slash
then

fi
```